# How Would I Find The Last Value Of Each Line In A Txt File, Using Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file

I have a file (ids.txt) that has some data that I want, but the file (ids.txt) has some extra information on it. How would I Extract It?

This is the main content of the file:

```
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     5276
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     5276
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     15372
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     1616
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     6596
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     5936
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     5276
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     15372
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     5936
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     5528
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     13572
  TCP        ESTABLISHED     11232
```

I would Like It to output:

```
5276
5276
15372
1616
13572
6596
5936
5276
13572
13572
13572
13572
13572
15372
5936
13572
13572
13572
13572
5528
13572
13572
13572
11232
```

Any Ideas? (What The Numbers Mean Is Irrelevant)

Comment: Safest way would be to isolate lines with the word `TCP` followed by one or more spaces, followed by the word `ESTABLISHED` followed by a sequence of one or more digits, using `findstr.exe`. If you place that as the command within a `For /F` loop, use the third token with no stated delimiters, the result will just be the number you require. Open a Command Prompt window, enter `for /?` and `findstr /?` to learn how to use them. Then use the search fscility at the top of the page, where you will be able to find thousands of similar examples of this methodology to assist you in writing the code.

Comment: From what I've tried with findstr.exe is that I cant get it to work in a for loop (probably because I suck as using for loops in batch, but whatever)

Comment: show your failing code - we are probably able to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I dont have the code anymore. I dont know how to use loops, I know how to use findstr.exe, but not loops.

Comment: The `findstr.exe` command, based upon my initial comment, should look something like this: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:"TCP[ ][ ]*ESTABLISHED[ ][ ]*[0123456789][0123456789]*" "P:\athTo\ids.txt" 2>NUL```. Then you'd put it in the `For /F` loop I mentioned, (using the 3rd token and no stated delimiters), like this: ```@For /F "Tokens=3" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:"TCP[ ][ ]*ESTABLISHED[ ][ ]*[0123456789][0123456789]*" "P:\athTo\ids.txt" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%G```

Comment: Try this in Command Prompt: `for /F "tokens=3" %I in (ids.txt) do echo %I`. To use that in a batch file, double the `%`-signs…

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory,
rem filename & output filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q74158152.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR %%y IN (%%b) DO SET "word=%%y"
 CALL ECHO %%word%%
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

I put your test data in `u:\your files\q74158152.txt` and the results appeared in a new file `u:\your results\outfile.txt`

Read each line from the source file, then set `word` to each "word" on the line in turn, so on leaving the loop, `word` contains the last word on the line. `Echo` that using a `call` to invoke the `echo` in a subshell.